# Problems with a code to get hydrological data from website [Brazil - ANA]

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

Developing a code to download Precipitation data from the ANA's (Water National Agency from Brazil) website.

I'm using Python with Selenium and I could get around 50% done. The website is all made with java, and I'm getting some issues to click in all the buttons that I need.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementClickInterceptedException

firefox=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='D:\_BaixarPrec\geckodriver')
firefox.get('http://www.snirh.gov.br/hidroweb/publico/medicoes_historicas_abas.jsf')

campo = firefox.find_element_by_id('form:fsListaEstacoes:codigoEstacao')
campo.send_keys('936000') #one station exemple

consultar = firefox.find_element_by_id('form:fsListaEstacoes:bt')
consultar.click()


firefox.implicitly_wait(3)
try:
  convencionais = firefox.find_element_by_id('dadosConvencionais').click()

except ElementClickInterceptedException:
  firefox.execute_script("window.scrollTo(2, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

I'm getting the return:

```
"ElementNotInteractableException: Element <div id="dadosConvencionais" class="tab-pane fade"> could not be scrolled into view"
```

it seams that I'm not been able to click in the bottom because I need to make a tab appear... I'm kind of stuck, if anyone can help.

Thanks either way